# Vaadin 7 osgi "Cookies disabled" error message

Tags: osgi, vaadin7

I'm playing around Vaadin v7  , deployed as osgi bundle on plain osgi framework with grizzly as http service provider .
Im able to start and load the page(1.jpg) , but when I click a button , I'm getting "Cookies disabled" error message (2.jpg) .
I saw there was similar issue with tomcat and httpOnly property , but couldn't find anything similar in grizzly .
please direct me where to start looking .
thanks in advance.
Stas

[image]

[image]